Navigator permission - `getCurrentPosition` or permissions.query` or both?
There's currently two ways to get a user's geolocation in the browsers for now:
https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_geolocation_getcurrentposition
https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.permissions
I'm currently using the first as I have a hard time using this with Firefox/Safari especially because some of the older browsers don't even have permissions.query. Is there a prescribed way to use one or the other or both?
